# login_form_seq ? in python

Tags: python

can some one give me example and explain how to use login_form_seq in python and login_form_data .. and this simple example but i don't know really how to deal with that !!

```
login_form_seq = [
('log', sys.argv[2]),
('pwd', word),
('rememberme', 'forever'),
('wp-submit', 'Login >>'),
    ('redirect_to', 'wp-admin/')]
z=0
login_form_data = urllib.urlencode(login_form_seq)
if z != 0:
    print " I love you Hamoud!"
else:
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
try:
    site = opener.open(host, login_form_data).read()
except(urllib2.URLError), msg:
    print msg
    site = ""
    pass
```

Please explain as well or don't explain and don't forget an example.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this...

```
import sys, urllib, urllib2
word = "YOUR WORD"
    login_form_seq = { 
        'log', sys.argv[2],
        'pwd', word,
        'rememberme', 'forever',
        'wp-submit', 'Login >>',
            'redirect_to', 'wp-admin/'
        }
    z=0
    login_form_data = urllib.urlencode(login_form_seq)
    if z != 0:
            print " I love you Hamoud!"
    else:
            opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    try:
            site = opener.open(host, login_form_data).read()
    finally: 
        print site
    except urllib2.URLError, msg:
            print msg
            site = ""
            pass
```